# ¿How to get the exact address of a cell? (VB.NET/INTEROP.EXCEL)

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-interop

Yes. I am using a library that almost nobody likes (COM / Interop). I am practicing doing a program that analize an Excel workbook, identify its columns and the user dials the type of each. Everything serves perfect, I can detect errors in the type of each column (for example if there is a string in a numeric column) but the only type that I am'm having problems is with dates. I asked a question here yesterday regarding dates (because I thought something) but I know from that question that dates are just numbers .... This is no problem because I can use Date.fromOADate.

Well, the situation I face is that if an Excel column contains information of dates and for example, you add a data string in that column of dates, when loading the Excel book in the program, that data string did not mark it as an error .. . but treats it as an empty cell (Thing that has surprised me).

this is the function that I wrote to mark the errors of each column

```
Protected Friend Function obtenerErroresColumna(ByVal column As String, ByVal page As String, ByVal tipe As String) As Integer
    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(column)) Then
        Dim cmd As String = "Select [" & column & "] from [" & page & "$]"
        Dim errors As Integer = 0
        Dim table As New DataTable
        Try
            Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, conexion)
            adapter.Fill(table)
            adapter.Dispose()
            For Each itm In table.Rows
                If (tipe.Equals("String")) Then
                    If (Not IsDBNull(itm(0))) Then
                        If (IsNumeric(itm(0))) Then
                            errors += 1
                            setValueError = itm(0)
                        End If
                    End If
                ElseIf (tipe.Equals("Numeric")) Then
                    If (Not IsDBNull(itm(0))) Then
                        If (Not IsNumeric(itm(0))) Then
                            errors += 1
                            setValueError = itm(0)
                        End If
                    End If
                ElseIf (tipe.Equals("Date")) Then
                    If (Not IsDBNull(itm(0))) Then
                        If (Not IsDate(itm(0))) Then
                            errors += 1
                            setValueError = itm(0)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            table.Dispose()
            Return errors
        Catch ex As Exception
            boxMessage("Error", ex.Message, My.Resources._error).ShowDialog()
            Return errors
        End Try
    Else
        Return 0
    End If
End Function
```

Ok, as I said the first two types is running good, the problem is when I start to compare date data type. I have this idea if the column is date type: If the program returns an empty cell (as I said earlier, the string data returns me as empty cells) then the program obtains the address of the cell to make a replacement. I have already written the method for substitution ... only as parameters would have to pass is today's date, the exact address of the cell and the column name.

I would like to check the adress of the current cell of the loop when the variable "itm" is Null (A4, B3, C50.... Etc)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reference to Excel.Interop in your code. For the first 26 columns you can use `Chr` :

```
Dim adr = Function(col%, row%) Chr(64 + col) & row

Dim B3 = adr(2, 3) ' "B3"
```

Comment: I use Interop to detect the number of columns, pages,and the used range. The function that I show here is just for compare data in cells... I would like to check the current cell of the loop when the variable "itm" is Null.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I found the solution of this problem. I didnt use interop but I get what I wanted.

First I needed to get the letter according to the column name. I found the web a function that returns the column letters of excel by passing as a parameter one number

```
Private Function ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(colIndex As Integer) As String
    Dim div As Integer = colIndex
    Dim colLetter As String = String.Empty
    Dim modnum As Integer = 0

    While div > 0
        modnum = (div - 1) Mod 26
        colLetter = Chr(65 + modnum) & colLetter
        div = CInt((div - modnum) \ 26)
    End While

    Return colLetter
End Function
```

I insert a counter in the function that detects errors, this counter would count the cells in the column while to get the column number, I create another function that carried the columns in a arrayList.

I take the indexOf function

```
Protected Friend Function obtenerErroresColumna(ByVal columna As String, ByVal hoja As String, ByVal tipo As String) As Integer
    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(columna)) Then
        Dim cmd As String = "Select [" & columna & "] from [" & hoja & "$]"
        Dim errores As Integer = 0
        Dim tabla As New DataTable
        Dim cell As Integer = 2
        Dim column As New ArrayList
        column = cargarMatrizColumnas(hoja)
        Try
            Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, conexion)
            adapter.Fill(tabla)
            adapter.Dispose()
            For Each itm In tabla.Rows
                If (tipo.Equals("Cadena")) Then
                    If (Not IsDBNull(itm(0))) Then
                        If (IsNumeric(itm(0))) Then
                            errores += 1
                            setValoresError = itm(0)
                        End If
                    End If
                ElseIf (tipo.Equals("Numerico")) Then
                    If (Not IsDBNull(itm(0))) Then
                        If (Not IsNumeric(itm(0))) Then
                            errores += 1
                            setValoresError = itm(0)
                        End If
                    End If
                ElseIf (tipo.Equals("Fecha")) Then
                    If (Not IsDBNull(itm(0))) Then
                        If (Not IsDate(itm(0))) Then
                            errores += 1
                            setValoresError = itm(0)
                        End If
                    Else
                        MsgBox("Direccion: " & ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(column.IndexOf(columna) + 1) & cell)
                    End If
                    cell += 1
                End If
            Next
            tabla.Dispose()
            Return errores
        Catch ex As Exception
            cajaMensaje("Error inesperado", ex.Message, My.Resources._error).ShowDialog()
            PantallaPrincipal.lbldireccion.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Return errores
        End Try
    Else
        Return 0
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

Source of the function: https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/11/13/convert-excel-column-number-to-name/